# Search for Windows-1252 characters using Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm attempting to find, and subsequently replace a few Windows-1252 characters with friendlier versions using Python. Specifically, I'd like to replace "µ" and "³" but I can't even naively match the characters. For instance:

```
with open(my_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "µ" in line:
            print "found"
```

The above does not work. However, the following does work within an interpreter:

```
line = "< 1.2 mg/dL(< 20 µmol/L) or N/A"
if "µ" in line:
    print "found"
```

I've tried various uses of `decode` without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**edit**

Below are two lines of text from the file I'm walking over:

```
< 1.2 mg/dL(< 20 µmol/L) or N/A
1.2 - 1.9 mg/dL(20 - 32 µmol/L)
```

Comment: You won't find anything `Windows-1252` unless you are loading it with that encoding in the first place. Your literal example works because you are using the same encoding for both your input and your value to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open it in an encoding-aware way:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(my_file, "r", "cp1252") as f:
    for line in f:
        if u"µ" in line:
            print "found"
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I haven't played much outside of ascii -- figured it was pretty straight forward

Comment: An essential article on Unicode that every programmer should read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: The above doesn't work actually. 'c1252' isn't known and when I specify 'Windows-1252', the code bails on the "µ" contains call due to a decode error. Any idea?

Comment: Should work now. Thanks for catching my typo, @AdamRosenfield, and for noticing the 2.x tag. I wonder why the OP didn't have trouble with `"µ"`?

Comment: Ah, adding 'u' to prefix the string worked, however the comparison is not matching that character

Comment: Do we have to do anything special in Python 2.x to read Unicode lines? I mostly use 3.x.

Comment: The above doesn't work with Python 3.3 either (using Py3 syntax of course...)

Comment: Hmm, actually, it seems CP1252 can't encode `μ`. Are you sure of the encoding used?

Comment: No, the encoding is Windows-1252

Comment: `cp1252` is the Python name for Windows-1252 - see the `codecs` docs. And it doesn't encode `μ`. Can you copy the `μ` by itself to another file and do a hex dump to see what bytes it's encoded as?

Comment: @TomZych yes it does encode `μ`, it's at `\xb5`. And I don't understand why there'd be a problem decoding `cp1252`, it includes almost every possible byte combination.

Comment: Oho! That's not a Greek "mu". That's a "micro sign". Different character. Try pasting this into the code and see if it finds it: `µ`. I've changed the answer code too.

Comment: @MarkRansom: what do you mean by "almost every possible byte combination"? cp1252 is an 8-bit encoding; it *can't* encode more than 256 characters.

Comment: @TomZych I only said "almost" because it has a few holes. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) there's no characters at `\x81,\x8d,\x8f,\x90,\x9d`. And it would have been more accurate to say "almost every byte value" but I didn't think of that wording until just now.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Oh, you meant that nearly all the bytes are mapped to characters. Sure. The problem was, I had thought this was a Greek mu, which is not one of those characters; whereas it was actually a "micro sign", which is. So the code reads a micro sign, and then searches for mu, and comes up empty. Code should work now.

Comment: Awesome! That did it, thanks again @TomZych and @MarkRansom! Sorry for all the confusion with characters.